# Display ECharts map using OpenStreetMap without Leaflet

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet, openstreetmap, echarts

I would like to render a geographical map inside my web page using the [ECharts library](https://github.com/apache/echarts).
ECharts needs a third party service to retrieve the images of the geographical region that it must display and I would like to use [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/).

The only available implementation that does something similar to what I need is this [echarts-leaflet](https://github.com/gnijuohz/echarts-leaflet) repository, which uses ECharts + Leaflet + OpenStreetMap and is not really up to date (it targets ECharts 3.6.2 while the current version is 5.2.2).

However, using both ECharts and Leaflet seems unnecessary to me (and increases the final bundle size) since ECharts and Leaflet *should (?)* do the same things and - as far as I can see - Leaflet and OpenStreetMap are two separate projects that does not depend on each other (am I wrong?).

Is there a way to use just ECharts and OpenStreetMaps avoiding Leaflet?

**Bonus:** the geographical map must be embedded inside a web page built with Angular 12. I tried to merge the code contained in [ngx-echarts](https://github.com/xieziyu/ngx-echarts) together with the one from [echarts-leaflet](https://github.com/gnijuohz/echarts-leaflet) but there are two issues:

- my code still requires Leaflet to run
- when I load the code inside [echarts-leaflet](https://github.com/gnijuohz/echarts-leaflet) I cannot manage to avoid Angular/Zone to hook into the event listeners set by Leaflet and this triggers a lot of unnecessary change detection cycles (it triggers on each `mousemove` event)

Comment: Did you figure it out?

Comment: Also interested in whether you managed to do this. Did you find a solution?

Comment: No solution, sorry (I gave up as achieving this requires a deep understanding of echarts internals that I do not have).